# How do I get CraveTV to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

I have Netflix running perfectly in Ubuntu and Chrome but I am unable to get my Cravetv (A Canadian Netflix like service by Bell)to work, how do I get it running?

My Specs
i3
4 gigs ram
intel 4000
ubuntu 14.10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

You can't natively that I know of.  I use VirtualBox and a Win10 inside.  It's not perfect but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Install Netflix-Desktop and then use that browser and go to CraveTV

https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-netflix-streaming-client-linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu ! Please provide descriptive answer. It would be helpful to others. And it would be better if the provided link become unavailable.

Comment: The `netflix-desktop` package is no longer available in the repository listed in the link.